# Turn image of lines into set of coordinates

Tags: computer-vision, polygon, computational-geometry, edge-detection

[image: floor plan]

Suppose I have an image of a floor plan like the one shown above. Is there a simple processing method to turn this image into a set of lines represented by coordinates [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)], [(x2,y2),(x3,y3)], ... , [(xn-1,yn-1),(xn,yn)]

Comment: Is this a picture representative of the ones you need to process, or just a explanatory sketch ? That can make a big difference.

Comment: this is Computer Vision task and there is no such thing as simple in CV 1.you need to provide real input image so we see what are you really dealing with 2.I would start with binarize the image by some treshold (but if the real image is different type/noise/ilumination then this may not be the way) 3.detect lines by hough transform or by inspecting/regressing the found pixels neighbors connecting straight lines together This process is also called vectorization so you know what to look for. This can be significantly simplified if lines are axis/angle alligned, and or constant known width

Comment: Have you solved your problem? do you still have any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find the co-ordinates of all the line you have in the image. It is very easy to find the co-Ordinates by following simple steps in c++:

1. Threshold binary Inverted
2. Apply [Thinning algorithm](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/) to reduce thickness.
3. Find NonZero Pixels in the Binary Image.
4. Find Contours & Apply Approx poly to Approximate the Points.

---

```
void thinningIteration(Mat& im, int iter)
{
    Mat marker = Mat::zeros(im.size(), CV_8UC1);
    for (int i = 1; i < im.rows-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < im.cols-1; j++)
        {
            uchar p2 = im.at<uchar>(i-1, j);
            uchar p3 = im.at<uchar>(i-1, j+1);
            uchar p4 = im.at<uchar>(i, j+1);
            uchar p5 = im.at<uchar>(i+1, j+1);
            uchar p6 = im.at<uchar>(i+1, j);
            uchar p7 = im.at<uchar>(i+1, j-1);
            uchar p8 = im.at<uchar>(i, j-1);
            uchar p9 = im.at<uchar>(i-1, j-1);

            int A  = (p2 == 0 && p3 == 1) + (p3 == 0 && p4 == 1) + 
                     (p4 == 0 && p5 == 1) + (p5 == 0 && p6 == 1) + 
                     (p6 == 0 && p7 == 1) + (p7 == 0 && p8 == 1) +
                     (p8 == 0 && p9 == 1) + (p9 == 0 && p2 == 1);
            int B  = p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9;
            int m1 = iter == 0 ? (p2 * p4 * p6) : (p2 * p4 * p8);
            int m2 = iter == 0 ? (p4 * p6 * p8) : (p2 * p6 * p8);

            if (A == 1 && (B >= 2 && B <= 6) && m1 == 0 && m2 == 0)
                marker.at<uchar>(i,j) = 1;
        }
    }
    im &= ~marker;
}

void thinning(Mat& im)
{
    im /= 255;
    Mat prev = Mat::zeros(im.size(), CV_8UC1);
    Mat diff;
    do 
    {
        thinningIteration(im, 0);
        thinningIteration(im, 1);
        absdiff(im, prev, diff);
        im.copyTo(prev);
    } 
    while (countNonZero(diff) > 0);

    im *= 255;
}

void main()
{
    Mat mSource_Bgr,mSource_Gray,mThreshold,mThinning;
    mSource_Bgr= imread(FileName_S.c_str(),IMREAD_COLOR);
    mSource_Gray= imread(FileName_S.c_str(),0);

    threshold(mSource_Gray,mThreshold,120,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    mThinning= mThreshold.clone();

    thinning(mThinning);

    imshow("mThinning",mThinning);
```

[image]

```
    vector<Point2i> locations;   // output, locations of non-zero pixels 
    findNonZero(mThinning, locations);

    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++)
    {
        circle(mSource_Bgr,locations[i],2,Scalar(0,255,0),1);
    }

    imshow("mResult",mSource_Bgr);
```

[image]

```
    //To Find the Lines from the image
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    /// Find contours
    findContours( mThinning.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { 
        approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 2, true );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < contours_poly.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(mSource_Bgr,contours_poly,i,Scalar(255,0,0),2);
    }
    imshow("mResult",mSource_Bgr);
```

[image]

```
}
```

Comment: that returns just the image he needs polygon in vector form... also you forget to specify what language is your code written in (or I missed it)

Comment: Thanks for pointing my misunderstanding @Spektre. Now things make sense i guess!